# Why is such a difference between the time of a query request within the kibana console and the query request from a python script

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve  **a lot**  of data from kibana using a python script. But I get unsatisfactory query time of execution, so I tried querying from within the  `dev_tools/console`  inside kibana. Doing a DSL query from console, it takes at a maximum of 15 secs in all cases to retrieve results.

From the python script I am trying to get the data using  `/_search?scroll=5m`  because I've read it is better to use scroll ((  `Scroll [ The Scroll api is recommended for efficient deep scrolling but scroll contexts are costly and it is not recommended to use it for real time user requests.]` )) as I just want to retrieve data, not real time requests. (or am I wrong?)

Within the Python script it takes ~3 mins at least using `requests` module.

The DSL queries used for each are the same. The difference is in the urls used:

- python using `requests` module:  `kibana_site:some_port_1/some_index/_search?scroll=5m`
- dev console:  `kibana_site:some_port_2/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console?_g=()`

Comment: HI! Which query do you run on dev_tools? You need only a query, or you should perform multiple queries? Have you tried the python high level client library - pip install elasticsearch?

Comment: Now I discovered it. I am going to give this a shot

Comment: There are two ways to do that query with that python library. the scroll method https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.scroll and the scan helpers' method  https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan